# Filter subsequent rows in a group after criteria is met in R

Tags: r, filter, subset

For the following sample dataset I need to delete any rows for the customer (CustomerID) after the first purchase (CustomerStatus = Purchased) is made. Some customers do not purchase the product, and I still want to retain any observations about these customers. The date variable is important to keep.

I'm having difficulties deleting rows within a group. The original data is not grouped as nicely as this, I'm trying to simplify the problem I'm having.  Any help is appreciated.

I have provided a sample dataset:

```
SalesPerson  CustomerID  Date       CustomerStatus
Amanda       2000       1/5/2017    Intro
Amanda       2000       1/6/2017    Email
Amanda       2000       1/15/2017   PhoneCall
Amanda       2000       2/15/2017   Purchased
Amanda       2001       1/3/2017    Intro
Amanda       2001       1/4/2017    Email
Amanda       2001       1/12/2017   PhoneCall
Amanda       2001       1/15/2017   Conference
Amanda       2001       2/4/2017    Purchased
Amanda       2001       3/17/2017   Meeting
Amanda       2001       3/20/2017   Email
Kyle         2002       1/19/2017   Intro
Kyle         2002       1/20/2017   Email
Kyle         2002       1/21/2017   PhoneCall
Sharon       2006       1/8/2017    Intro
Sharon       2006       1/10/2017   Meeting
Sharon       2006       1/19/2017   Purchased
Sharon       2006       1/30/2017   Conference
Sharon       2006       2/10/2017   Purchased
```

The output should be as such:

```
SalesPerson  CustomerID  Date       CustomerStatus
Amanda       2000       1/5/2017    Intro
Amanda       2000       1/6/2017    Email
Amanda       2000       1/15/2017   PhoneCall
Amanda       2000       2/15/2017   Purchased
Amanda       2001       1/3/2017    Intro
Amanda       2001       1/4/2017    Email
Amanda       2001       1/12/2017   PhoneCall
Amanda       2001       1/15/2017   Conference
Amanda       2001       2/4/2017    Purchased
Kyle         2002       1/19/2017   Intro
Kyle         2002       1/20/2017   Email
Kyle         2002       1/21/2017   PhoneCall
Sharon       2006       1/8/2017    Intro
Sharon       2006       1/10/2017   Meeting
Sharon       2006       1/19/2017   Purchased
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'SalesPerson', 'CustomerID', create a logical index to `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(SalesPerson, CustomerID) %>% 
     filter(cumsum(lag(CustomerStatus == "Purchased", default = FALSE))<1)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   SalesPerson, CustomerID [4]
#   SalesPerson CustomerID      Date CustomerStatus
#         <chr>      <int>     <chr>          <chr>
# 1      Amanda       2000  1/5/2017          Intro
# 2      Amanda       2000  1/6/2017          Email
# 3      Amanda       2000 1/15/2017      PhoneCall
# 4      Amanda       2000 2/15/2017      Purchased
# 5      Amanda       2001  1/3/2017          Intro
# 6      Amanda       2001  1/4/2017          Email
# 7      Amanda       2001 1/12/2017      PhoneCall
# 8      Amanda       2001 1/15/2017     Conference
# 9      Amanda       2001  2/4/2017      Purchased
#10        Kyle       2002 1/19/2017          Intro
#11        Kyle       2002 1/20/2017          Email
#12        Kyle       2002 1/21/2017      PhoneCall
#13      Sharon       2006  1/8/2017          Intro
#14      Sharon       2006 1/10/2017        Meeting
#15      Sharon       2006 1/19/2017      Purchased
```

Comment: Thank you The solution works. I was not familiar with the lag and cumsum functions, but I understand how they work now. Could you tell me how you approached the problem? I was not even considering logical indexing.

Comment: @user8215919  After the group by operation, created the logical index `CustomerStatus == "Purchased"`, then took the `lag` of it so that the position of TRUE value gets changed to the next position.  Then do, a cumulative sum and `filter` the values less than 1.  If you have trouble understanding, split the code into parts and check it with `mutate(id = lag(CustomerStatus == "Purchased", default = FALSE))`